# Can't find binary after compile of Ada (GNATBench 2013) within Eclipse 3.7

Tags: eclipse, ada

## Ada (GNATBench 2013) Eclipse 3.7 (32-bit) Windows 7

After what appears to be a successful compilation, I cannot run (nor even find) the Ada executable.

Eclipse consoule output:
[gnatmake, -d, -PC:\Eclipse32\workspace-ada\hello1\hello1.gpr, hello1.adb] [hello1]
gnatmake -d -PC:\Eclipse32\workspace-ada\hello1\hello1.gpr hello1.adb 
[gnatmake, -d, -PC:\Eclipse32\workspace-ada\hello1\hello1.gpr, hello1.adb] for [hello1] completed Jul 14, 2013 12:04:47 PM CDT.

Anyone have a step-by-step set of notes on compiling Ada 2013 under Eclipse 3.7?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can not find a way for Eclipse to 'prompt' me (or automatically) to set the -P option mentioned by user 'flyx' (thx) above which is required for a successful build of an Ada program (.exe). So I guess I'll just leave it as this ==> the -P option has to be manually added to the Compiler package of the .gpr (Eclipse Ada Project) file.

Answer (score 1):

You can specify the location of your executable in the project file `hello1.gpr`, like this:

```
project Hello1 is
   -- ...
   for Exec_Dir use "bin";
   -- ...
end Hello1;
```

Relative paths get resolved from the directory that contains the project file. **The directory has to exist!** If `Exec_Dir` isn't set, it defaults to `Object_Dir`, which can be set in the same way. `Object_Dir` defaults to the directory where the project file is located, so if none of these two directories is specified, you should find your binary in

```
C:\Eclipse32\workspace-ada\hello1\
```

As GNATBench just calls `gnatmake` for compilation, this problem isn't GNATBench-specific. You can read about the project file format in detail [here](http://docs.adacore.com/gprbuild-docs/html/gprbuild_ug.html).

It might be that GNATBench provides a visual editor for the project file like the GNAT Programming Studio does (I never used GNATBench myself, so I don't know about that). If that's the case, you should be able to set the directory of your executable there.

I'm not aware of any step-by-step guide for using GNATBench. There seems to be very little information about it available, even from AdaCore (might be different if you are a customer). If you're just starting to use Ada, you might want to consider to use the [GNAT Programming Studio](http://libre.adacore.com/tools/gps/) instead - it has a solid online tutorial and manual available.

Comment: "The directory has to exist!" - from the command line you can use `-p`, which means to create any directories needed.

Comment: Thanks for all your feedback.  I have looked under the default directory C:\Eclipse32\workspace-ada\hello1\ as you suggested and I see some .* file and a project hello.gpr file but no executable.  Could it be that I am not compiling the code after all?  How can I check that Eclipse has GNAT installed correctly and is compiling the Ada source?  Or better yet, from the command-line, how can I check that GNAT is even installed correctly on Windows 7?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Eclipse does not install GNAT at all. You should install it separately. To check whether GNAT in installed on your system, just type `gnat` into the command line. It should display its version and a list of available commands. If the command cannot be found, it's either not installed or not in your `PATH`.

Comment: I had mistakenly thought that GNATbench installed the GNAT compiler.  I have now downloaded and installed the GNAT compiler and now can compile via Eclipse. Compile info: Ada File(s) Compilation [hello1]
gnatmake -ws -c -u -PC:\Eclipse32\workspace-ada\hello1\hello1.gpr hello1.adb 
gcc -c -g -g -gnato -gnatwa -gnatQ -gnat12 -I- -gnatA C:\Eclipse32\workspace-ada\hello1\src\hello1.adb
Ada File(s) Compilation for [hello1] completed Jul 20, 2013 2:10:37 PM CDT.

Comment: I exceeded the comment buffer limit so I had to send 2 comments.  This is a continuation of the above comment. However, I get an error when trying to run the executable -- Error starting process. Cannot run program "C:\Eclipse32\workspace-ada\hello1\hello1.gpr": Launching failed...  I suspect I am running it incorrectly via Eclipse.  Nevertheless, I do not (when searching) find a 'hello1.exe' file on my system.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well, Eclipse tries to launch `hello1.gpr` which isn't an executable file. I think there is something wrong with your Eclipse configuration, because it invokes gnatmake with `-c` (compile only), your project file and your source file (invoking it on the project file without further switches would get it to compile all source files). No wonder that you have no executable if GNAT does not link it. You can try to call just `gnatmake -Phello1.gpr` from the command line and see whether it produces the executable (which it should). If that works, you have to get Eclipse to do exactly that somehow.

Comment: gcc works from DOS command-line.  But from DOS command-line Get this error C:\Eclipse32\workspace-ada\hello1>gnatmake hello1.gpr
gcc -c -x ada hello1.gpr
hello1.gpr:1:01: compilation unit expected  ....  Eclipse does not show error (hmmmmmm!)
hello1.gpr:8:28: missing "use"
gnatmake: "hello1.gpr" compilation error                             Source code is --- with Ada.Text_IO;
use Ada.Text_IO;
procedure hello1 is
begin
   Put_Line ("Hello WORLD!");
end hello1;

Comment: Please append the contents of your `hello1.gpr` to your question. I think it's broken.

Comment: project Hello1 is

   for Main use ("hello1.adb");
   for Source_Dirs use ("src");
   for Object_Dir use "obj";

   package Compiler is
      for Default_Switches ("ada") use ("-g", "-gnato", "-gnatwa", "-gnatQ", "-gnat12");
   end Compiler;

   package Builder is
      for Default_Switches ("ada") use ("-g");
   end Builder;

   package Ide is
      for Compiler_Command ("ada") use "gnatmake";
      for Compiler_Command ("c") use "gcc";
   end Ide;

end Hello1;

Comment: Your commands are a bit hard to read here in the comments. Apparently you are executing `gnatmake hello1.gpr` from command line, right? That should be `gnatmake -Phello1.gpr`, because it's a project file. You project file contents looks fine.

Comment: gnatmake works fine from DOS command-line.  Problem is with Eclipse build and run. Any ideas?

Comment: Well, then Eclipse tries to compile the project file without using `-P`. As I said, I do not actually know GNATBench, and there is no documentation publicly available, so I guess I cannot help you further.

Comment: Does anyone else know how to set Eclipse to compile the project file with the -P option?  I have looked in the Eclipse IDE and it is not obvious how this is done.

Comment: Btw - I can do this manually by modifying the .gpr file but would of course like to be able to have Eclipse automatically handle this switch.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: I can not find a way for Eclipse to 'prompt' me (or automatically) to set the -P option mentioned by user 'flyx' (thx) above which is required for a successful build of an Ada program (.exe).  So I guess I'll just leave it as this ==> the -P option has to be manually added to the Compiler package of the .gpr (Eclipse Ada Project) file.  HTH